# How to run a batch file in siebel escript and execute plsql package through a batch file by passing a variable and to get the output

Tags: siebel

My requirement is to execute a plsql package through siebel escript.  For that, I am planning to write a batch file which can be invoked in the escript.
 in the batch file,  I want to execute the package. But stuck at passing the input to package and get the output from it. Please help me with the code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest answer might be using Clib Send Command Method. This can be used to run commands on the siebel server, on any OS. eg:

Clib.system("dir /p C:\Backup");

So you could try invoking your bat file

Clib.system("C:\custom.bat arg1 arg2");

You will have to handle the variables in the bat file (or .sh) file and invoke your PLSQL from there.

The flip side is that there is no way of getting any output from the command line back to Siebel.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/eScript/C_Language_Reference101.html#wp1008859

Answer (score 0):

You can get the output back into Siebel indirectly by having the command pipe it to a text file and having Siebel process that file.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to call the batch with Clib.system and have it save the output into a file. You then need to have some BS/Workflow to read the file and delete it.

It will work reliably if you are careful with the file naming to avoid concurrency issues.